# How Klogd communicate with syslogd?

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, syslog, busybox

On my system I have syslogd writing userpsace log messages into a persistent file on flash. I want to do same thing with my klogd messages. From manpages it seems Klogd by default send messages to console and to syslogd. But I am not able getting any kernel module messages in the same file.

Dmesg give me complete dump of module messages. So I know my module that generate kernel dump is working fine. I am not sure why I am not getting klogd messages. By default we do not have /var/log/messages. For testing I created one but I got partial dump from klogd into /var/log/messages file but that only when I'm restarting klogd.

Seems I am missing something. Do syslog.config control what messages it receive from klogd or it will receive all?

I am using Busybox's syslogd and Klogs implementation and not the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

klogd -f specifies log file you want to use for kernel logging, have you tried that